# Force ajax call to clear cache

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, xmlhttprequest, clear-cache

I have a cms in which I can change positions of objects. After each position change ajax call updates the whole list of objects. But unfortunately some data is stored in cache and no changes are visible. Is there a way to force clearing cache with javascript/request/other ? I've tried 'cache: false' in `$.ajax` but it's not working.

Here's a sample page :

http://ntt.vipserv.org/manage/playforward

And my js :

```
$(".object-position").livequery("change", function() {
    $("#objects-list input").attr('disabled', true);
    var action = $(this).attr('name');
    var position = $(this).attr('value');
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var model = id.split("-")[0];
    var object_id = id.split("-")[1];

    $("#loader").show();
    $("#loader").fadeIn(200);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: "/manage/update_position/",
        data: "action=" + action + "&model=" + model + "&object_id=" + object_id + "&position=" + position,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $("#loader").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                $("#loader").hide();
            });
            $("objects-list").html(data["html"]);
            $("#message").show();
            $("#message").fadeIn(400).html('<span>'+data["message"]+'</span>');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#message").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    $("#message").hide();
                });
            }, 1500); 
        }
    });
    $("#objects-list input").attr("disabled", false);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
$("objects-list").html(data["html"]);
```

Try this instead:

```
$(".objects-list").html(data["html"]); // forgot leading dot?
```

Also, it looks like you're trying to replace the contents of the `.objects-list` table with some html that includes the `<table>` element itself. So you'd have `<table...><table...>`, etc., after the `.html()` content replacement.

Answer (score 20):

What `cache: false` does is to add the time to the request data, so each request is effectively unique and therefore bypasses the browser's cache.  I wonder if the fact that you are using a data string rather than an object is causing problems here.  Try using an object instead:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: "/manage/update_position/",
    data: {
        "action": action.
        "model": model,
        "object_id": object_id,
        "position": position
    },
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        //[snip]
    }
});
```

Comment: I do confirm - this actually works. cache:false adds timestamp to url and thanks to this, everytime new content is loaded.

Answer (score 7):

Just replace

```
url: "/manage/update_position/",
```

with

```
url: "/manage/update_position/?nocache="+Math.random(),
```

to force reloading the page not using the browser’s cache.

Comment: That could easily muck a routing system up.  If you're going to do this manually, make it a request parameter instead: `"/manage/update_position/?nocache="+Math.random()`

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I forgot to include a `"?"` in my original post. It should have been: `"/manage/update_position/?"+Math.random(),`